# How to use python to download images from my telegram bot on a specific day

Tags: python, telegram

I have created a telegram bot using Botfather. Currently, there are many images sent to this bot and i want to download images sent on a particular day. For example, I want to download all images sent on 28 Feb.

How do I do this in python?

I have tried reading documentation on python telegram but I can't understand much.
Appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Try python library `python-telegram-bot`.